# c++ array initialization

Tags: c++, arrays

```
float minTime[7]={FLT_MAX};
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
        cout << "Min: " << minTime[i] << endl;
```

Why do I get in the following output :

```
Min: 3.40282e+038
Min: 0
Min: 0
Min: 0
...
```

Shoudln't all have the same value as the first one? As it is refered here:
[C++ Notes](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/array-initialization.html)

Comment: From your link: Missing initialization values use zero
If an explicit array size is specified, but an shorter initiliazation list is specified, the unspecified elements are set to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shoudln't all have the same value as the first one?

Nopes! When an array is partially initialized the non-initialized array elements are value initialized (*zero-initialized* in this case).

**C++03 Section 8.5.1/7**

> If there are fewer initializers  in  the  list  than  there  are  members  in  the  aggregate,  then  each  member  not explicitly initialized shall be **value-initialized** 
>   (8.5).
>   [Example:
>
> ```
> struct S { int a; char* b; int c; };
> S ss = { 1, "asdf" };
> ```
>
> initializes `ss.a` with  1, `ss.b` with "asdf",  and `ss.c` with  the  value  of  an  expression  of  the  form
>   int(), that is, 0.  ]

Comment: But that wasn't if I'd did:
float miniTime[7]={FLT_MAX,FLT_MAX} and the remaining 5 would be 0? If I only set one of the elements all should be the same, or not?

Comment: Technically, the rest of the elements are value-initialized, not zero-initialized. Not that there is any difference for floats :)

Comment: @Armen : Yes! Added relevant text from the standard.

Answer (score 4):

Your linked page says "...the unspecified elements are set to zero."

This is correct; as such, only the first element in your array was specified to be `FLT_MAX`, the rest are initialized to zero. If you want to set them all to the same value you can use a for-loop, or more succinctly:

```
std::fill_n(minTime, 7, FLT_MAX);
```

---

As a warning, C++ is a hard language. This means lots of people have lots of misinformation, and this is especially easy to find on the internet. You'd be better off learning from a [book on our list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). (And yes, the ones *not* on our list are so because they too contain misinformation!)

Comment: @doubter: That's okay, it'll happen again and again to all of us. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, only first value is initialized with the supplied value, other values are value initialized as per standard.

Comment: As per standard, they are value-initialized, not default initialized. Not that there is any difference for POD types, including floats